# What is the values of sample size when saying small or large sample?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, small-sample, large-data

A basic question in statistics. When it is said that:

- Fisher's exact test is employed when sample sizes are **small**.
- The normal distribution can be used as an approximation to the binomial distribution if n is **large**.
- If the samples are **reasonably large** we can use the normal approximation to the binomial...

what are the considered values for **small** and **large (reasonably large)** sample sizes in such statistical cases? What are the criteria of considering a sample size to be small or large?

Comment: The quality of a normal approximation to the binomial depends on the sample size _and_ the proportion because the binomial distribution becomes more and more skewed as the proportion approaches 1 or 0.

Comment: There's no universal criterion. Often its possibke to get some idea how close various approximations might be and decide for yourself whether it's close enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The old rule of thumb was that the sample size is too small when the expected count of one of the cells of the contingency table is lower than five. Recall that the expected count of a cell is the ratio $$\frac{row\_count \times column\_count}{total}.$$

In

> http://www.biostathandbook.com/small.html and
>   http://www.biostathandbook.com/fishers.html,

owing to the expansion of computing power, the author argues in favour of a new rule of thumb:

'*I recommend that you always use an exact test (exact test of goodness-of-fit, Fisher's exact test) if the total sample size is less than 1000. There is nothing magical about a sample size of 1000, it's just a nice round number that is well within the range where an exact test, chi-square test and G–test will give almost identical P values.*'

Here is the underlying bibliographical reference:

> McDonald, J.H. (2014). Handbook of Biological Statistics (3rd ed.), 86-89.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know any other references discussing about it?

Comment: No but I'll look for some tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you. This is for a citation.

Comment: The first statement supposedly applies to chi-square tests for contingency tables. There aren’t guarantees but many authorities have written that the rule is very cautious. Fienberg in his monograph on categorical data and Jeffreys in his _Theory of Probability_ both give 1 as a rule of thumb for minimum expected count.

Comment: I was not aware of the use of a different threshold. Thank you for the information. I am quite surprised as to why a monograph such as Kanji's '100 Statistical Tests' would not even mention this alternative.